# Getting Gson TypeToken from class name as a String

Tags: java, reflection, gson, typetoken

I want to do something like this - deserialize a class with generic type using Gson. The following code works like a charm.

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ActionTask<UptimeAction>>() {}.getType();

ActionTask task = (ActionTask) gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

But what if the type is provided as a String? I imagine something like the following.

```
String className = "UptimeAction";

Type type = ... // get the type somehow

ActionTask task = (ActionTask) gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: whats classname in this case, relevance?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Guava docs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken), you can create a method like this:

```
static <T> Type mapActionTask(Class<T> innerType) {
    return new TypeToken<ActionTask<T>>() {}
            .where(new TypeParameter<T>() {}, innerType)
            .getType();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
String className = "com.foo.UptimeAction";
Type type = mapActionTask(Class.forName(className));
```